# Регулярные выражения и жадные квантификаторы

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Написал такую регулярку:

```
/<a(.*)href=\"http:\/\/url1(.*)\">(.*)<\/a>/s
```

Все хорошо, но если в тексте перед url1 будет ссылка, то очевидно, что будут съедены обе ссылки. Например:

```
<a href="http://url0">url0</a>
text
<a href="http://url1">url1</a>
```

Comment: Используйте минимальную квантификацию, все  

    .*
замените на  

    .*?

Comment: Чтобы заменялась ссылка с url1

Comment: рекомендую вот [это][1]. Отлично помогает при составлении регулярок


  [1]: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: @Сахарок, ссылки в комментах работают немного иначе:`[ссылка](http://example.com)`

Answer (score 1):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
/<a[^>]+href=\"http:\/\/url1(.*?)\">(.*?)<\/a>/s
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, а в вопросе разве указано, что используется именно PHP?

Comment: @СашаЧерных, да, вы правы, убрал, "PHP-обертку".